# deploying multiple apps on a single cluster

Tags: kubernetes, digital-ocean, istio

I am wondering how to deploy multiple applications such as springboot app, nodejs app etc.on a single kubernetes cluster that has a single istio load balancer.
Is it pssible?

I am a beginner in devops so need some guidance on this.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: isnt that the whole point? Thats what ingress is for. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. Moreover this is the exact purpose of the LoadBalancer - to be a single point of entrance for multiple applications.

If you deploy an [example application](https://istio.io/latest/docs/setup/getting-started/#bookinfo), you will create three versions of *reviews* application (*reviews-v1*, *reviews-v2*, *reviews-v3* - as far as K8s and Istio are concerned, those are three different apps). With the use of [Virtual Services](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#virtual-services) and [Destination rules](https://istio.io/latest/docs/concepts/traffic-management/#destination-rules), Istio manages traffic between those three applications.

Since you are a beginner, I would strongly recommend thorough read of [Istio documentation](https://istio.io/latest/docs/), especially [Tasks](https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/) and [Examples](https://istio.io/latest/docs/examples/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also achieve your requirement using istio single loadbalancer by creating each of your app by istio virtual service >> service >> deployment.

There are many other alternative ways to acheive this unless you are looking for specific other features of istio.
One alternative way is to deploy NGINX ingress conroller and create ingress for each of your app(deployment) a detailed guide is here https://tasrieit.com/expose-multiple-apps-with-one-loadbalancer-in-kubernetes/